# SamlAssertionKeyIdentifierClause

Tags: wcf, wif

Trying to call a WCF service from an MVC web application using the below snip to open the channel.

When I inspect the token, in VS it looks correct, the claims are correct.

```
var channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken<IAmTheService>(token);
channel.MyMethod(param);
```

> 'SessionSecurityToken' does not support 'SamlAssertionKeyIdentifierClause' creation.

I'm not sure where to even start looking.  =(

Ideas?

**EDIT**

The reason it fails is because i needed to use the bootstrapToken to issue another token for the service instead of the sessionToken dirctly.

Comment: Did you make a call to `ChannelFactoryOperations.ConfigureChannelFactory<IAmTheService>(factory)` prior to calling the `CreateChannelWithIssuedToken`?

Comment: Also, is your token a GenericXmlSecurityToken. This forum post says that it has to be, even though the documentation and method signature suggest any SecurityToken will do. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/2079c77e-04f2-4ae8-9859-ea9bad8b061d

Comment: Maybe? var factory = new ChannelFactory<IAmTheService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress));
            factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
            
            factory.ConfigureChannelFactory<IAmTheService>();

Comment: It should be a GenericXmlSercirtyToken  var genericToken = channel.Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
                 var handlers = FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;
var token = handlers.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(genericToken.TokenXml.OuterXml)));
                 var identity = handlers.ValidateToken(token).First();
var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(ClaimsPrincipal.CreateFromIdentity(identity));           
                 FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);

Comment: @William - if the code snippet above is what you have (`factory.ConfigureChannelFactor<IAmTheService>()`), that may be where your issue lies - ConfigureChannelFactory is a method of ChannelFactoryOperations, not ChannelFactory.  It should be `ChannelFactoryOperations.ConfigureChannelFactory<IAmTheService>(factory)`.

Comment: I was using the session token instead of the sessionToken.bootstraptoken.  doh!